# chart problems am4core legend format

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm working with amCharts and trying to create a Pie Chart where the legend displays the total before the nom_prenom. Currently, it's displaying nom_prenom: percentage.

I've tried modifying the legend settings, but I couldn't achieve the desired format. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
            chart.data = filteredData;
            // chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
            // // chart.legend.position = "right";
            // // // chart.legend.maxHeight = 150;
            // chart.legend.scrollable = true;  
            /* Create legend */
            chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();


        



            /* Create a separate container to put legend in */
            var legendContainer = am4core.create(legenddiv, am4core.Container);
            legendContainer.width = am4core.percent(100);
            legendContainer.height = am4core.percent(100);
            chart.legend.parent = legendContainer;




            chart.events.on("datavalidated", resizeLegend);
            chart.events.on("maxsizechanged", resizeLegend);
```